# Email notification when S3 bucket permission changed

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I would like the get the email notification to specific mail id, if anyone updated the permission like list, write, read, make public of objects inside the specific S3 Bucket.

we have the situation where multiple people in our organization can allowed to access the S3 buckets. Each can upload/download their own team related files. While doing this some people make mistake by making the whole bucket as public, or enabled the write and list permission.  We are unable to identify this problem when this permission enabled and couldn't take immediate action revoke that permission . To avoid this we require to notification mail service when someone changed the permission on particular S3 Bucket.

Please help how to handle this situation.

Comment: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/how-to-detect-and-automatically-remediate-unintended-permissions-in-amazon-s3-object-acls-with-cloudwatch-events/

Answer (score 0):

Write better permissions, attach exclusive deny permissions to low level users to specific buckets, which will overrule the existing bad policies. Even if you get a notification when someone changes a bucket policy it might take you some time to act on that. CloudTrail API detection and email notification can be done but it will still be open to vulnerabilities. I believe efforts should be focused on figuring out access permissions primarily, then an event based email trigger.

@Amit shared the correct article for that: [How to Detect and Automatically Remediate Unintended Permissions in Amazon S3 Object ACLs with CloudWatch Events | AWS Security Blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/how-to-detect-and-automatically-remediate-unintended-permissions-in-amazon-s3-object-acls-with-cloudwatch-events/)